# C++ Drawing arcs in Direct2D Device

Tags: c++, direct2d

I need to draw an arc in a D2D device, is there a function that does this?(something like DrawLine or DrawEllipse)
Otherwise, i've seen that there is the ArcSegment function that returns a D2D1_ARC_SEGMENT structure, how can i draw that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `D2D1_ARC_SEGMENT` can be used when populating a path geometry (`ID2D1PathGeometry`). Once you've added the arc you want to the path, you can draw it using `ID2D1RenderTarget::Draw/FillGeometry()`.

Answer (score -2):

Im not too familiar with Direct2D so I am unaware of any specific function that would allow you to do this, however it does not stop you from implementing your own function to achieve what you want.

I recommend looking into splines and how they are calculated [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline)

seems like a good place to start. You could then generate your Arc with with the formula and several DrawLine calls.

Edit: or even [this](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) may serve you better.